# Adding a space between two words once

Tags: excel, vba

I completed code to remove any data in front of a string, add some text (with a space) to the front and store it back in the cell.

However, every time I run the macro (to check if changes that I've made are working for example), a new space is added in between the words.

The code that removes anything before the name and adds the required string.  I have called a `InStr` function and stored the value in integer pos. Note that this is in a loop over a specific range.

```
If pos > 0 Then
    'Removes anything before the channel name
    cellValue.Offset(0, 2) = Right(cell, Len(cell) - InStr(cell, pos) - 2)

    'Add "DA" to the front of the channel name
    cellValue.Offset(0, 0) = "DA " & Right(cell, Len(cell) - InStr(cell, pos) - 2)

    'Aligns the text to the right
    cellValue.Offset(0, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
End If
```

An additional "DA" is not being added and I haven't made any other functions to add spaces anywhere. The extra space is not added if adding "DA " is changed to "DA".

I'd prefer not to add another function/sub/something somewhere to search and remove any extra spaces.

What the string is AND what is in front of the string is unknown. It could be numbers, characters, spaces or exactly what I want it to be. For example, it could be "Q-Quincey", "BA Bob", "DA White" etc. I thought that searching through the cell for the string I want (Quincey, Bob, White) and altering the cell as needed would be the best way.

---

Solution that you all helped me come up with:

```vb
If pos > 0 Then
    modString = Right(cell, Len(cell) - InStr(cell, pos) - 2)
    'Removes anything before the channel name and places it in the last column
    cellValue.Offset(0, 2) = modString
   
    'Aligns the last column text to the right
    cellValue.Offset(0, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    
    cellValue.Offset(0, 2).Font.Size = 8
    
    'Add "DA" to the front of the channel name in the rightmost column
    If StartsWith(cell, "DA ") = True Then
        cellValue.Replace cell, "DA" & modString
    Else
        cellValue.Replace cell, "DA " & modString
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I don't understand `InStr(cell, pos)`

Comment: Should it not be `Right(cell, Len(cell) - pos - 2)`?

Comment: Right(cell, Len(cell) - InStr(cell, pos) - 2) is one I found while searching online.

Comment: Why do you put a value in an Offset range object? I think Range.Replace could help you out too. Use a wildcard in your search.

Comment: Each cell in the loop may not have the same thing I need to remove and replace. It could be "Q-Quincey" or "QA Quincey", or any other permutation. I thought that searching for "Quincey" and modifying the cell as needed would be the best way.

Comment: So everything in front of "Quincey" needs to be replaced with "DA "?

Comment: Tried to edit previous comment, it would not work. I tried changing InStr(cell, pos) to (-pos-2), to (cell, cell) and in both cases the string I wanted to keep was cut off.

Comment: @JvdV Correct. What is in front of "Quincey" is unknown. It could be numbers, characters, spaces or exactly what I want it to be. Should I amend my post to reflect this?

Comment: @BrownishMonster you were right. I'm not sure what happened. My noobness probably. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something you can work with:

---

***<sub>Sample data:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>Sample code:</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

With Sheet1.Range("A1:A4")
    .Replace "*quincey", "AD Quincey"
End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Result:</sub>***

[image]

Comment: I neglected to say that I'm not always looking for "Quincey" and have edited my post (again) to show this. In each column, the rows have different names (quincey, bob, white) and for specific targeted ones I want to add "DA" to the front. I will keep plugging away. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @dkraemer, you can fill an array with the strings you looking for and loop that array using the exact method I demonstrated above

Comment: I ended up fixing it with a simple if/else within the loop. I have a boolean "startswith" function that checks the passed value against a passed prefix value. I guess I was hoping that I was missing something within my code, but this was an extra 2 lines and I'm satisfied.

Comment: So this issue is solved? If so, feel free to upvote/mark an answer from here that you feel has answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to go about it through a loop you should remove some redundancies in your code. For instance, refering to cell.offset(0,0) doesn't make sense.

I would set the target cells to a range and simply edit that cell with out placing the unwanted strings in another cell.

**EDIT:

I'd try something like this.**

```
nameiwant = "Quincy"
Set cell = Range("A1")
If InStr(cell, nameiwant) > 0 And Left(cell, 3) <> "DA " Then
    cell.Value = "DA " & nameiwant
End If
```

Comment: I wasn't very clear in the original post and have added an edit to (hopefully) make what's happening more clear. I see what you're saying about the offset(0, 0) though. I did that because I'd used the offset for other code and copy/pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, it seems you want to replace the first "word" in the string with something else.  If that is always the case, the following function, which makes use of Regular Expressions, can do that:

```
Option Explicit
Function replaceStart(str As String, replWith As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "^\S+\W(?=\w)"
    replaceStart = .Replace(str, replWith)
End With
End Function

Sub test()
    Debug.Print replaceStart("Q-Quincy", "DA ")
    Debug.Print replaceStart("BA Bob", "DA ")
    Debug.Print replaceStart("DA White", "DA ")
End Sub
```

The debug.print will -->

```
DA Quincy
DA Bob
DA White
```

The regular expression matches everything up to but not including the first "word" character that follows a non-word character.  This should be the second word in the string.

A "word" character is anything in the set of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Seems to work on the examples you present.

Comment: I'm unsure if this solves the problem. Because I don't know for sure what will be in front of "Quincey, Bob, White", I can't make a direct replacement statement. The data changes depending on how the user specifies it. I could pass replaceStart the current cell and search for the desired word and then replace everything that ISN'T that word with "DA", but I'm already doing that, basically.

Comment: @Dkraemer If your examples are not representative of your real data, crafting a solution that works on your real data may not be possible.  Possibly if you present real examples, the various solutions could be modified to work.

Comment: @Dkraemer With this solution, it doesn't matter what is in front of "Quincey, Bob, White".  As demonstrated, it replaces whatever is in front with `DA `. Examples of where this approach doesn't work might help to refine the solution.  In addition, if you need to **save** the *in front* phrase, that can also be easily done.

Comment: thank you. I will look further into this. I'm trying to account for every possible input; perhaps that's unreasonable? For example, if it were "wbijnqeidfjnwQuincey" or something.

Comment: @Dkraemer you will either need an unambiguous rule, or a lookup table to solve the problem.

Comment: thank you, I'll look into the lookup table. Always an opportunity to learn something new.